# Where Condition not working in Join

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am not able to get result as expected, here is following lambda query

```
var query = from au in db.Users
                     join auc in db.UserRoles.Where(ac => !ac.Role.Contains("Supplier"))
                     on au.UserName equals auc.UserName
                     into g
                     from ab in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { UserName = au.UserName };
```

What I want is, all `UserNames` from `Users` table which do not have `Supplier` role in `UserRoles` Table. Where condition is not working in Expression. And User and UserRoles both are different tables without any relationship exists

Thank You in Adv

Answer (score 0):

My concept is that you need to add a

```
where ab == null
```

However, I'd write it like this, so I wouldn't have to worry about the behaviors of join (duplication, etc)

```
IQueryable<string> query =
  from au in db.Users
  where !au.UserRoles.Any(ur => ur.Role.Contains("Supplier"))
  select au.UserName;
```

Comment: There is NO relationship in Users and UserRoles.. they both are different tables

Comment: And Count is Zero

Comment: define a relationship: "au.UserName equals auc.UserName"